# Java EE workspace in cloud9

Tags: jakarta-ee, cloud9-ide

Is it possible to create a workspace for a Java EE (mainly servlet, jsp) project in cloud9?

If so, then how is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think it can work, because the Cloud9 documentation says VMs have the Java SDK installed. However, I recommend you to use some embedded webserver, such as Jetty Maven plugin to run your application. If you already know Maven, then you can find useful informations about the Jetty plugin here: http://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html

Note: to run the embedded application server properly, you should run Jetty with

```
mvn jetty:run -Djetty.host=$IP -Djetty.port=$PORT
```

command to make it work properly with Cloud9's redirection and let them to make your application available on `http://<workspacename>-c9-<username>.c9.io`  URL

But please keep in your mind, Cloud9 does not support Java language at this point, so expect some missing features, like correct code completion.